# RuntimeError: Failed to create exception

Tags: python, sql, tkinter, mariadb

As described in my first question, I have built a main GUI and from there I click on a button where a second GUI opens. In the second GUI I have entry-boxes where I can enter data and save it in the database. For each GUI I have a separate table in the database.

In the other GUIs it works, but in the GUI 'dispergrader' I get an error message.

This is the complete error log:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "C:\Users\Zlatan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__ 
return self.func(*args)   

File "C:\Users\Zlatan\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\polymer\dispergrader.py", line 106, in submit
c.execute(sql_command, values)

RuntimeError: Failed to create exception
```

The line 106 is this one:

```py
c.execute(sql_command, values)
```

This is the code of the submit function:

```py
# create submit function for database
def submit():
    sql_command = """
                INSERT INTO dispergrader 
                (Dispergrader_model, Test_name, Compound_name, Illumination, Volume_fraction, 
                    Reference_Bank, Exposure_time, Order_name, Batch_number, Batch_name, Threshold_Dispersion, 
                    Color_channel, Spot_disper, X_disper, Y_disper, Z_disper, White_area, Dispersion, Average_size, Agg_size_Std_Dev) 
                    VALUES(
                    %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, 
                    %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""

    values = (Dispergrader_model.get(), Test_name.get(), Compound_name.get(), Illumination.get(), Volume_fraction.get(),
                Reference_Bank.get(), Exposure_time.get(), Order_name.get(), Batch_number.get(), Threshold_Dispersion.get(),
                Color_channel.get(), Spot_disper.get(), X_disper.get(), Y_disper.get(), Z_disper.get(), White_area.get(), Dispersion.get(),
                Average_size.get(), Agg_size_Std_Dev.get())

    # insert into table
    c.execute(sql_command, values)

    # commit changes
    conn.commit()

    # clear textboxes
    Dispergrader_model.delete(0, END)
    Test_name.delete(0, END)
    Compound_name.delete(0, END)
    Illumination.delete(0, END)
    Volume_fraction.delete(0, END)
    Reference_Bank.delete(0, END)
    Exposure_time.delete(0, END)
    Order_name.delete(0, END)
    Batch_number.delete(0, END)
    Batch_name.delete(0, END)
    Threshold_Dispersion.delete(0, END)
    Color_channel.delete(0, END)
    Spot_disper.delete(0, END)
    X_disper.delete(0, END)
    Y_disper.delete(0, END)
    Z_disper.delete(0, END)
    White_area.delete(0, END)
    Dispersion.delete(0, END)
    Average_size.delete(0, END)
    Agg_size_Std_Dev.delete(0, END)
```

For testing purposes, each column has the data type text. Like the other tables.

Any suggestions where I'm doing wrong?

[Screenshot of HeidiSQL with MariaDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1EEa.jpg)

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you verified that all of the calls to `.get()` are returning the values you expect them to return?

Comment: Have been able to identify the error.
I just forgot to write down the variable: "Batch_name" in the values - .get() section. That's it.